# Symfony2 - FOS UserBundle - Override Register form with Drop Down List with data from Database

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I'm trying to build a very simple app with symfony2 .

I've installed and configured FOS UserBundle with HWI Oauth2 .

It's working fine , but I want to modify the register form so that it has a dropdown list with data from my database pulled out by doctrine .

I did not found anything on Symfony doc. .

Can anybody provide a suggestion ?

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))

        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))


         **/**** This Works and give a dropdownlist but i want to get this list from database instead of hard coded data how can I achieve that ? *****/** 
        ->add('status_type', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            '' => 'Please Select...',
            'developper' => 'Android Developper',
            'architect' => 'Android or Mobile Architect',
            'mobile' => 'Mobile Developper',
            'web and mobile' => 'Web and Mobile Developper',
        )))

        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example code;

```
$builder->add('status_type', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Status',
    'property' => 'status_name',
));
```

or if you need a custom query: (you need to adjust the query for your schema)

```
$builder->add('status_type',
              'entity',
               array(
                     'class'=>'AcmeDemoBundle:Status',
                     'property'=>'status_name',
                     'query_builder' => function ($repository)
                     {
                         return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                ->where('s.status_type = ?1')
                                ->setParameter(1, 'basic')
                                ->add('orderBy', 's.sort_order ASC');
                     }
                    )
              );
```

for more information, you can find the related documentation at http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html